# Use a NSURLconnection for multiple posts to API

Tags: objective-c, http-post, nsurlconnection

I having a situation here where I have some templates (objects), which I want to push to my backend. Now When the users presses the synchronise button, there is a connection to the backend form which I get all the templates. The templates on the IPAD app are compared to those that were transferred from the backend. If a template on the IPAD app has the ID(0), then there is a post to the backend. the backend then returns the saved template with his ID (to add to the local stored template).

Now I think my problem here is that I'm using the same connection (templateupdateconnection => bad name...) for all of those posts to the backend. The actual problem is that in the connectiondidfinishloading method, I only get a response on the last template that was posted to the backend.

Anyone who knows how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance!!

**THE CODE**

```
-(void)syncRegistrations:(NSArray *)arrayOfRegistrations{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Registration" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *Data = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    BOOL old=FALSE;


    for(int registrationCounter = 0; registrationCounter < arrayOfRegistrations.count; registrationCounter ++){

        NSDictionary *dictRegistration = [arrayOfRegistrations objectAtIndex:registrationCounter];

        for(Registration *registration in Data){

            if([dictRegistration objectForKey:@"id"] == registration.id){

                old = TRUE;

            }
            else if ([registration.id intValue]==0){

                NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"form\":%@}",registration.form.id];
                NSLog(@" de jsonrequest: %@",jsonRequest);

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mybackend/registrations"];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
                NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
                [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

                self.registrationtoupdate = registration;
                self.registrationUpdateConnection = NULL;
                self.registrationUpdateConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                [self.registrationUpdateConnection start];

                registration.id=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1];
                [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
                old=TRUE;

            }


        }

        if(old==FALSE){
            //nieuwe template toevoegen
            Registration *registration = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Registration" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            registration.id = [dictRegistration objectForKey:@"id"];
            registration.form = [self getFormByID:[dictRegistration objectForKey:@"form"]];
            [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        }

        old=FALSE;

    }

    //[self getRC];
    [self performSelector:@selector(getRC)  withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

}
```

**CONNECTIONDIDFINISHLOADING METHOD**

```
else if([connection isEqual:self.registrationUpdateConnection]){

    NSDictionary *dictRegistration = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.registrationdata options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"de data van de registratie is: %@",dictRegistration);

    NSLog(@"de registration to update is: %@",self.registrationtoupdate);
    self.registrationtoupdate.id = [dictRegistration objectForKey:@"id"];

    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encapsulate the `NSURLConnection` and all relevant state data into a class. Let that class have a `start` method which asynchronously starts the connection and a completion block which has a parameter *result* representing the eventual result of the request. That way, you don't mismatch response data with other connections.

Then, in the completion block, reference the corresponding context (registration to update), get the JSON representation and update the context *on the correct thread or queue* appropriately for the given managed object context (see below "Thread Confinement"):

So, basically:

```
        else if ([registration.id intValue]==0) {
            // setup the request
            NSMutableURLRequest *request =  ...
            MyHTTPRequestOperation* op = 
                [[MyHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                     completion:^(void)(id result)              
                {
                    if (![result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
                        assert(result != nil && [result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]);
                        NSDictionary* dictRegistration = 
                           [NSJSONSerializationJSONObjectWithData:result 
                                                          options:kNilOptions 
                                                            error:&error];
                        // Todo: check if dictRegistration has the required type 

                        id newRegistrationID = [dictRegistration objectForKey:@"id"];

                        // Update the model on the thread/queue you defined for the 
                        // NSManagedObjectContext:
                        [self updateRegistration:registration withID: newRegistrationID];
                    }
                    else {
                        // an error occurred
                    }                        
                }];
            [op start];

            registration.id=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1];
        }
```

You should be familiar with NSModelObjectContext and "Thread Confinement".

see also:  `-(id)initWithConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)ct`

[Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html)

Core Data Best Practices at [WWDC/2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)  (requires dev account)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm seeing where you want to go, but can you please give me a full example with the new connection class, cause I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

@CouchDeveloper, thanks for putting me on the right track!!

The final solution, wasn't to create a subclass of the NSURLConnection, but just using the completion block in combination with a simple NSURLConnection. check the following code:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request  queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil){

         NSDictionary *dictrc = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         NSLog(@"de data van de rc is: %@",dictrc);
         rc.id = [dictrc objectForKey:@"id"];

         [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
     }


 }];
```

Comment: This is completely valid. Just, the convenient method won't work for more advanced use cases like authentication, saving data to a file, etc. Getting your own creation of a MyHTTPRequestOperation right - _can_ be from simple to _challenging_.

Comment: Here is an example of an _extremely simple_ implementation of a HTTP Request class: https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/5764723  it is meant for experimenting and getting an idea what's under the hood of `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

Comment: An important note: the execution context of the completionBlock for `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is _unspecified_. That means, it can be _any_ thread. You should definitely read "Core Data and Thread Refinement" and execute `save:` on the correct thread or queue! The code above will very likely crash and exhibit unexpected behavior.